# margin: 0 auto; not working when linked to external css

Tags: html, css, external, center

When I linked to my external style-sheet, it seems my wrapper styles are broken. If I paste the styles into the head on my index.html, it works just fine, but not when linking to a .css. All other css rules work perfectly either way, only the wrapper style appears to break.

The only rule applied to the wrapper is to center it within the browser, so if there is another reasonable way to accomplish this I'm all ears.

the wrapper css:

```
#wrapper { 
    width: 960px; 
    margin: 0 auto; 
}
```

and the html (minus content):

```
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="header">
        </div>
        <div id="nav">
        </div>
        <div id="content">
            <div id="cont_left">
            </div>
            <div id="cont_right">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="footer">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Any help or advice would be great.

EDIT: here is the full css:

```
#wrapper {
width: 960px;
margin: 0 auto;
}

#header {
width: 960px;
height: 144px;
background-image: url(../images/header.jpg);
background-repeat: repeat-x;
margin-bottom: -14px;
}

#logo {
margin-right: 48px;
margin-top: 33px;
float: right;
}

#logo a img {
border-top-width: 0px;
border-right-width: 0px;
border-bottom-width: 0px;
border-left-width: 0px;
border-top-style: none;
border-right-style: none;
border-bottom-style: none;
border-left-style: none;
}

#tagline {
margin-top: 90px;
margin-left: 48px;
float: left;
clear: both;
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 18px;
font-style: normal;
color: #CCC;
}

#nav {
width: 960px;
height: 48px;
background-image: url(../images/nav_bar.jpg);
background-repeat: repeat-x;
}

#nav_bar {
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 14px;
font-style: normal;
font-weight: bold;
margin-left: -50px;
padding-top: 14px;
}

#nav_bar li {
display: inline;
padding-left: 58px;
}

#nav_bar li a {
text-decoration: none;
color: #999;
padding: 4px;
}

#nav_bar li a:hover {
color: #fff;
background-color: #666;
}

.current {
color: #CCC;
}

#content {
float: left;
width: 960px;
background-image: url(../images/content.jpg);
background-repeat: repeat-x;
}

#cont_left {
width: 40%;
margin: 48px;
float: left;
}

#cont_right {
width: 40%;
margin: 48px;
float: right;
}

#footer {
clear: both;
height: 48px;
width: 960px;
background-image: url(../images/footer.jpg);
background-repeat: repeat-x;
}

#footer_list {
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 12px;
color: #666;
font-style: normal;
text-align: center;
padding-top: 16px;
}

#footer_list li {
display: inline;
padding: 18px;
}

#footer_list li a {
text-decoration: none;
color: #666;
padding: 4px;
}

#footer_list li a:hover {
color: #000;
text-decoration: underline;
}

h1 {
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 48px;
line-height: 20px;
font-weight: normal;
margin: 0px;
padding-top: 0px;
padding-bottom: 12px;
}

p {
font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 12px;
line-height: 20px;
}

body {
background-image: url(../images/background.jpg);
background-repeat: repeat-x;
}
```

EDIT TO ADD: Website is not live, therefore I have no link to provide, sorry. Still in early development stages, got stuck on this issue.

Comment: The problem is almost certainly contextual. You've probably stripped out whatever the problem is by reducing the test case to this.

Comment: Check your external url. Make sure it is completely valid. How are you attaching it?

Comment: Is your stylesheet being referenced properly?

Comment: Are you using only one CSS include?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will not make a difference whether your css rule is in an external stylesheet or in a <style> tag in head. Things to try;

1. Validate your css file (will inform you of typos) http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/
2. Do you have multiple css files? If so, try to include this stylesheet last.
3. Use firebug (or chrome inspector if you prefer) to inspect your #wrapper element, to see if your definition show up at all (and if its overruled and by what).

I would love to see your entire solution if possible, so i can poke around :)

Comment: never used W3C before. This came up: 

8 Parse Error /* CSS Document */ <style type="text/css"> #wrapper { width: 960px; margin: 0 auto; }
156   Parse Error </style>

Comment: aha! in your css file, remove the html tags - only include whats *inside* of the style tags, and bob's your uncle!

Comment: thanks, but unless i did this wrong, it was no help. same problem persists.

Comment: @Isaac do you have a link to your css file? from the parser error it looks like you have html <style> tags in your css file. Also: try moving the #wrapper definition to the bottom of your css file

Answer (score 1):

View source of the page you are using and click on the CSS document you link you have linked. It should pull up a CSS page with your styles, if not, you're either 1) not linking it correctly or 2) there is a permissions issue on the server.

**ADD:** Check it in developer tools (F12 -> IE, left-click>inspect Element -> chrome, Firefox).

Answer (score 1):

What browser are you using?  I've just tried your sample in IE8 and it won't centre at all unless I include the XHTML doctype:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
```

No idea why, or if you have this or not, but it may help.

Comment: yes, sorry, I do have the doctype included in the head of my html.

Comment: wait, i have: 

    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

not aware of the difference between strict and transitional.

Comment: Can you try it on a few different browsers and see if you have the same problem on all of them?

Comment: i've been using firefox. problem persists through IE and chrome as well.

Answer (score 0):

I have never had this problem before. You may not have the link correct

Make sure that you attached you style sheet correctly:

```
<link href="Default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

If it is in a folder (say Styles for ex):

```
<link href="Styles/Default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

If your webpage is in a folder then you need to add "../" to the front

```
<link href="../Styles/Default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

You can also try `!important`

```
#wrapper { 
    width: 960px; 
    margin: 0 auto !important; 
}
```

If that does not work, then right click the `wrapper` element and click "inspect element" in chrome. This will show you all applied css on that element, and what has been over written by what. This will give you a better idea of what is actually going on (downloading Firebug for firefox is also helpful)

Comment: My css is linked thusly:    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

Comment: if this was the problem, wouldn't every css rule be non-functional? not just the wrapper. it is the only issue that appears.

Comment: It would. Do you have other css? I was under the impression that the css you showed was the only css you were doing.

Comment: thanks for your help though. unfortunately that doesn't seem to be the problem.

Comment: And the css file is in the right folder? The html that you are using is a single file or is a template with components?

Comment: Do you have firebug? Can you see what the css for that element is when you link the sheet externally? **Edit** Also make sure that you have nothing overwriting this css in your style sheet, if this is the case, then that is why the css will work in the head (it is later then the style so it is what the page will go off of)

Comment: html is a single file. css is in the correct folder. 
just added the complete css

Comment: You have to have some css that is overwriting the `wrapper` css. Launch it in chrome and inspect `wrapper`. That way you can see what is overwriting that css. You can also try adding `!important` to both css calls in `wrapper`, but this may be the less then ideal way to do it

Comment: just tried using important, to no avail. 
although, i'm not familiar with this technique so i may be doing it wrong.

Comment: site is not live, i have no link sorry. i could upload the files if you're willing to take a look through.